# Axis lines=center and label placement together with compat=newest

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
axis lines=center,
%compat=newest
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
      \addplot gnuplot {x**2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If I use `compat=newest` or `compat=1.x` with x > 2 I get the following output:

[image: output 1]

If I don't use any compat statement I get what I the following (desired) result:

[image: output 2]

With `compat=default` the result is even different: The ylabel is flushed to the left.

I don't understand why compat does affect the result in this way. My understanding is that `compat=newest` or `compat=default` should not change anything. Can you explain what's going on here?

My pgfplots version is 1.12.1.

Comment: I can't run your code, but even the author of `pgfplots` discourages from using `compat=newest` because if a new version comes around that changes code, your documents will break. Pick a version and stick with it (according to the document). Try `compat=1.12` and then go backwards: `1.11`, then `1.10`, until you find your desired result.

Comment: I can go backwards to 1.2 without getting the desired result.

Comment: I get your desired result with any `compat`, if I change your plot to `\addplot {x^2};`, but I suppose that's not the same thing.

Comment: I get the desired result with all values for `compat` except `pre 1.3` if I set `compat=...` *before* `axis lines=center`. So the `compat` Information is already known when the style of the `axis lines` is changed.

Comment: You have to have the compatibility setting before anything. EDIT: I didn't see @esdd's  comment.

Comment: @esdd Could you convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the desired result with all values for `compat` except `pre 1.3` if I set `compat=...` **before** `axis lines=Center`. So the `compat` information is already known when the style of the `axis lines` is changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,% <- set compat first!
    axis lines=center,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
        \addplot gnuplot {x**2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]